# redirect não é enviado ao navegador

Tags: python, redirecionamento, flask

Fiz 3 paginas no meu website: um para cadastrar, um para login e outro servindo como a pagina inicial. preciso que depois que o usuário se cadastrar ele seja enviado para o login, que caso seja bem-sucedido lhe envie para a pagina inicial.

Estou usando o `request e url_for` do Flask para isso, porém, quando ele é executado, ele não altera o url da pagina, ele apenas executa o script da pagina (lá no `app.py`). toda a parte logica no servidor funciona certinho.

Procurei em quase todo o Stackoverflow (incluindo o gringo), até na ajuda da Google, mas nada se referindo ao mesmo problema que o meu. É como se o `redirect` não fosse enviado ao navegador, penso isso pois na aba *network* do "inspecionar", a pagina recebe apenas o script JS, CSS, do Avast e dela mesma (html). não recebo nenhum erro no console, eu apenos aperto para enviar e a pagina recarrega, mesmo o servidor alegando que está tudo certo e que o usuario é valido.

Pensei em usar o `webbrowser`, mas ele abre o link em outra aba.

Preciso redirecionar em 3 locais: da `/home` para o `/register`, e do `/register` para o `/login`, depois, se bem-sucedido: `/login` para `/home`:

**app.py/login:**

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def login():
    error = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        username = data['User']
        password = hassh.blake2b(data['Password'])

        valid=''
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM WebApp")
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        a = ''
        for i in username: #adiciona um SALT no hash
            if i.lower() == 'a' or i.lower() == 'e' or i.lower() == 'i' or i.lower() == 'o' or i.lower() == 'u':
                a+=i #coloca as vogais do username na variavel
            else:
                pass
        b = ''.join(reversed(a))
        password += b

        for row in rows:
            dbUsername = str(row[0])
            dbPass = str(row[1])
            if username == dbUsername and password == dbPass:
                valid = True
                break
            else:
                valid = False

        print(str(valid))
        if valid == False: #verificar se o login falhou
            return '<p>Credenciais invalidas</p>', redirect(url_for('login'))

        else: #se não falhou, então deveria enviar o usuario para a home
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
            #return webbrowser.open('http://192.168.0.4:5000/',new=0)

    return render_template('login.html')
```

**home.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" dir="ltr">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='home.css') }}">
</head>
<body>    
    <p>aaaa</p>
    <h1>bbbb</h1>



    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='home.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

**app.py/home:**

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def home():
    print('home')
    #return redirect(url_for("login"))
    #flash('gloria')
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Como faço esse `redirect(url_for())` realmente redirecionar? só funcionou na home, que não tem nada. Alias, quando ele redirecionar, é como realmente ele não enviasse para o servidor: ele executa a `def home()` e tudo que tem nela, mas não muda a pagina.

**Edit1:** descobri que o redirect não funciona dentro do if.

Comment: tentei criar um metodo em outro arquivo, tendo esperança que era algum erro de sintaxe ou algo assim, mas continua a mesma coisa

Comment: Onde está a funçao home?
Eu acho que o problema não é com o redirect, substitua os return redirect por return "Home", e return "Login", assim você saberá se o Login aconteceu de fato.
Pois acho que ele não está chegando em "return redirect(usr_for('home'))

Comment: ele redireciona o servidor para executar a ´def()´ da rota, mas não redireciona o usuário para a pagina. vi que pode ser culpa do Ajax que estou usando para comunicação front-back.

Comment: sei que a função da home (def) é executada (usei print), mas que o redirect não